Shiny App flickers on clicking the dropDown button from shinyWidgets
I have implemented the drop down button from shinyWidgets on my app. But on clicking the button to generate dropDown, the app flickers. How can I remove the flickering of the app?
additionalFilterHeader<- function(){
  dropdown(
    inputId = "additionalFilter",
    label = tags$span(style="font-size:15px;","Filters"),
    shinyjs::hidden(tags$div(id ="FilterDiv1",
             Header1())),
    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"),
                shinyjs::hidden(tags$div(id = "FilterDiv2",
                         Header2())),
                shinyjs::hidden(tags$div(id = "FilterDiv3",
                         Header3()))
    ),
    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"),
                shinyjs::hidden(tags$div(id = "FilterDiv4",
                         Header4())),
                shinyjs::hidden(tags$div(id = "FilterDiv5",
                         Header5()))
    ),
    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"),
                shinyjs::hidden(tags$div(id = "FilterDiv6",
                         Header6())),
                shinyjs::hidden(tags$div(id = "FilterDiv7",
                         Header7()))
    ),
    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"),
                shinyjs::hidden(tags$div(id = "FilterDiv8",
                         Header8())),
                shinyjs::hidden(tags$div(id = "FilterDiv9",
                         Header9()))
    ),
    actionButton("Settings", "Apply")
  )
}

header1<- function(){
  numericInput(inputId = "Year1",
               value = "",
               label = tags$span(style="color:black;","Year"),
               width = NULL
    
  )


Share a minimal reproducible example of the problem so that developers here can help you.
